# MS powerpoint can't be started

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

When opening powerpoint (ppt), it always prompts to reboot powerpoint for many rounds until it is finally opened. This happens to ppt 2003, 2007 on winxp. Any solution? I also reinstalled, used 2007 to replace 2003, but never worked.

Comment: Did you look at the Event Viewer to see what the system is saying the problem is? Is there a message about WHY PowerPoint needs to reboot?

Comment: where is the event viewer

Comment: always wants me to open in safe mode

Comment: event viewer is in your Window start menu and music2myear asked about the exact error message PowerPoint gives you. Anyway, Windows XP an Office 2007 do not get security updates anymore for years, so that machine should not be connected to the internet.

Comment: @Furty why not connected to internet

Comment: Because you don't want to be infected by malware - probably because of such your Office is not working. When was the last update of your antivirus software if you have any? Also there is no updated browser anymore for XP. So if Powerpoint is more important than internet for you and you can not afford a new computer, try [SoftMaker Freeoffice](https://www.freeoffice.com) - it is lighter than LibreOffice.

Comment: there's reason why i stick to xp. so can u give any clue for the error? how's 'freeoffice' compared to ms office?

Comment: Reason is? No one can help you with "the error", if you don't update the question with exact messages (and events from event viewer, if there are any entries during Powerpoint launch). When i do a "freeoffice vs microsoft office" Google search [this as 2nd English link](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3305332/freeoffice-2018-review.html)

Comment: reason is xp gives some convenience in some matters. thanks for the freeoffice suggestion. but it hasn't a feature of recording narrations as in powerpoint?

Comment: How conveniant can it be to loose all your data because of malware, that came through because of your unsupported OS? I can not install FreeOffice parallel to the full SoftMaker Office 2018 - it does not seem to have an audio recording feature (but you can add separately recorded files), however it can export the presenation as video including the added sound.